# Java & XMLDSig: Reference with no URI

Tags: java, xml-signature, xml-dsig

I'm trying to sign some text using XMLDSig with javax.xml.crypto.dsig.* package. I need to make a reference to some content being signed. And according to project requirements this reference should not have any URI, it means not <Reference URI="">...</Reference>, but <Reference>...</Reference>.

I haven't found any info whether it is possible and correct, but requirement says that XMLDSig allows such references, maximum one per signature.

Have someone faced the same problem? What can be done to produce signature with such reference using javax.xml.crypto.dsig.* package and no magic?

As I understood the package mentioned above only allows to reference some data with URI (or with empty URI), but not without any URI at all. May be I've missed something in its usage?

Comment: This is odd. I'm trying to sign a XML with URI, but can only get it signed without it.

Comment: Probably, you're mixing the terms. I'm talking about creating a signature Reference object with no URI, not about XML without URI.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, XML Signature can contain one `Reference` with no URI, but you need to tell sign context how to find object referenced this way. This can be done by using custom implementation of `URIDereferencer`.

So, to reference some content in signature without any URI you can do the following:

```
Reference dataReference = xmlSigFactory.newReference(null, <your digest method>, <your transformations list>, <needed type>, <id>);
```

Where the very first `null` parameter means `null` as URI, i.e. no URI.

To make this reference valid you need to specify your custom `URIDereferencer` implementation in `DOMSignContext` object which holds all the references to content being signed. This custom `URIDereferencer` should contain logic to find content being signed, it's your own implementation so you should know how to find needed content.

Answer (score 0):

Create NoUriDereferencer implement URIDereferencer and set it for your XmlSignContect

```
public class NoUriDereferencer implements URIDereferencer {

private Node data = null;

public NoUriDereferencer(Node node) {
    data = node;
}

public Data dereference(URIReference ref, XMLCryptoContext ctxt) {
    return new NodeSetData() {
        public Iterator iterator() {
            return Collections.singletonList(data).iterator();
        }
    };
}
}
```